# Are questions on research methodology on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

This [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90879/31917) about whether (in this case statistical) research always needs a hypothesis made we wonder: Are questions about research methodology on topic?

In general, questions on specific research problems are considered off-topic and frequently migrated to the respective 'sister site' that deals with substantive problems (e.g. biology.se).

Does this rule also apply to research methods (as opposed to substance)? For some issues related to statistical methods, crossvalidated.se seems a more appropriate place. For other, mostly qualitative or experimental methods, there is no dedicated 'sister site' (but perhaps physics.se accepts questions on experiment design).

Note that I wrote 'methods' and not 'process'. Process might include things that are clearly on-topic here, such as how to frame a research problem in a particular kind of publication, funding, collaboration etc. Whether the linked question is really about methods or process is a separate but also relevant issue.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Should we be more welcoming of “technical” questions?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/should-we-be-more-welcoming-of-technical-questions)

Comment: I like your initial idea! Thanks for bringing this up. Could you, however, give an example in your post? I have difficulties to imagine a meaningful question in which users can be of help (without reading pages of specific research design or methdology for project X).

Comment: @Stefan_W There are various examples in the methodology tag, like [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91399/how-to-cite-obvious-things-or-make-them-credible) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83109/what-are-cautions-to-take-with-second-hand-data-in-an-interview) question. I'm not sure what you mean by "your initial idea".

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Initial in the sense of "Should we discuss methodology?" and I say definitely "yes!", but how to go from here is my concern. The question on 'second hand data' is for me foremost an ethics question &I don't know how the other one is related to methodology?! By 'methodology' I mean "the general research strategy that outlines the way in which research is to be undertaken and, among other things, identifies the methods to be used in it. These methods, [...] define the means or modes of data collection or, sometimes, how a specific result is to be calculated." (wikipedia)